# NSMutableArray make sub arrays of every two objects and inject a blank string at the end

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

**Question**: Is this the most *efficient* way of doing this or is there a better way?

**Requirements**: make a new array of objects containing unique (non duplicate) sub array object pairs of strings and at the end inject a blank string.

Say if we have an array of objects pet names in this case (Harley, Jake, Levi, Zoe)

```
NSArray *objects = @[@"Harley",@"Jake",@"Levi",@"Zoe"];
```

**NSMutableArray** *_petNames* which we will fill with the re-done objects array. I had thought about using **NSRange** to help build the sub array but ended up not going that route.

Here is my code:

```
    //we need to add a blank string at the end of the array we created.
    //then we need to iterate over the array and make subArrays with every 2 objects in the array.
    BOOL addedDualArrayWithSpacer = NO;
    //build our array of pet names!
    if (!_petNames) {

        NSArray *dualArray = nil;
        _petNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [objects count] ; r++) {
            //[r , r+1] test for exsistence of r+1
            if ([objects containsObject:objects[r]] && ((r+1) < [objects count]) ) {

                NSLog(@"range is [%li] and max [%lu]", (long)r, (unsigned long)[objects count]);
                NSLog(@"exsists = %@ , %@", objects[r], objects[r+1]);

                dualArray = @[@[objects[r], objects[r+1]]];
                //test for exsistence of obj[r]
                if (([_petNames indexOfObject:objects[r]] == NSNotFound)
                    && (![_petNames containsObject:objects[r]])
                    ) {
                    //this will push the "range" out by one! thus hopping to the next correct item!
                    if((r+1) < [objects count]) r= r+1;
                    [_petNames addObjectsFromArray:dualArray];
                }
            }
            else{

                if (![_petNames containsObject:objects[r]]
                    && !([_petNames indexOfObject:objects] == NSNotFound)){
                    dualArray = @[@[objects[r], @""]];
                    addedDualArrayWithSpacer = YES;
                     [_petNames addObject:dualArray];
                }
            }
        }
        //now add blank object for ADD PET button if addedDualArrayWithSpacer is NO
        if (!addedDualArrayWithSpacer) {
            NSArray *cheat = @[@""];
            [_petNames addObject:cheat];
        }
```

This code outputs in the console the new _petNames array in this form (which is what I need):

petnames [(
        (
        Harley,
        Jake
    ),
        (
        Levi,
        Zoe
    ),
        (
        ""
    )
)]

I have a habit of overcomplicating my code and any help making this more efficient would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by "containing unique (non duplicate) sub array object pairs". Are you saying you want to simply throw out duplicate names from your objects list? (i.e., @[@"Harley",@"Jake",@"Levi",@"Zoe",@"Jake"] becomes @[@"Harley",@"Jake",@"Levi",@"Zoe"]? Or is it unique pairs that you are concerned about (i.e., @[@"Harley",@"Jake",@"Levi",@"Zoe",@"Jake",@"Fred"] results in three unique pairs, two of which contain @"Jake")? Or do you mean something else entirely??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
_petNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[objects count] / 2 + 1];
BOOL isOddCount = [objects count] % 2;
// if there's an odd amount of objects in source array, we need to make one more iteration
// 'j' is the iteration counter
for (NSUInteger i = 0, j = 0, n = [objects count] / 2 + isOddCount; j < n; ++j, i += 2)
{
    NSMutableArray *subArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:objects[i]];
    [subArray addObject:j == n-1 && isOddCount ? @"" : objects[i+1]];
    [_petNames addObject:subArray];
}
if (!isOddCount)
    [_petNames addObject:@""];
```

If there's an odd number of objects in source array, e.g. `@[@"Harley",@"Jake",@"Levi",@"Zoe",@"Rex"]`, the result will be [( ( Harley, Jake ), ( Levi, Zoe ), ( Rex, "" ) )].

P.S. In your code, `[objects containsObject:objects[r]]` is always true and both conditions in `([_petNames indexOfObject:objects[r]] == NSNotFound) && (![_petNames containsObject:objects[r]]` check the same thing, so you could easily remove one of the conditions (same applies to the `else` branch).

Comment: FYI - (in testing this code) some cases like the even number - it does not add the @"" object at all at the tail end because the isOddCount is YES. Other times with just ONE pet name it works and adds the @"". In larger odd numbers like arrays of 7 items it does not add the @"" either.

Comment: I thought you wanted @"" to be last object if previous is a pair of pets, but if last array contains only one element then @"" should be the second element in the single pet array.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. for example (Henry, @""), (Harley, Beth, Max, @"") and (@"")-if no names. At any rate the @"" should always appear at the end of the items whether it is a new row or added to a row with only one item in it. I hope that is clearer! Thanks for responding.

Comment: ok updated my answer, please check. The only thing I'm still not sure about: if there's an odd amount of objects, the last array (before a single @"") should consist of the only pet name or pet name and @"": `( (Henry, @""), @"")` or `( (Henry), @"")`?

Comment: the correct is (Henry, @"") because the @"" should only appear once.

Comment: j is always less than n it is never iterated as far as i can see in the code. which leads to stack overflow in memory. should I add a j++?

Comment: oops I'm sorry, yes please add `++j` in the end of the `for`

Comment: UPDATE: actually there was a part of the answer that was leaving out names. I fixed it by doing this.

if (!isOddCount)
                [subArray addObject: objects[i+1]  ];
            else
                [subArray addObject:j == n-1  ?   @"" : objects[i+1]  ];

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the modulo operator `%` and enumeration. Here block-based enumeration as it gives the index fore free, while in fast enumeration (`for (id obj in objects)`) an expensive `indexOfObject:` would be needed. And to remove duplicate names I first use an set.

```
NSArray *objects = @[@"Harley",@"Jake",@"Levi",@"Zoe", @"Harley", @"Henry"];
objects = [[[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:objects] array];
NSMutableArray *petNames = [@[] mutableCopy];
[objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx % 2 == 0) {
        [petNames addObject:[@[obj, @""] mutableCopy]];
    } else {
        [tempPetNames lastObject][1] = obj;
    }
}];
```

As `@""` will create one object at compile time, it is a cheap operation to stuff it in an array, just to overwrite it in most cases.

---

I am not sure, if I understand your requirement for uniqueness correctly. The code above will first eliminate all duplicate form the names, while the following will first pair them and than remove any duplicate pairs.

```
NSArray *objects = @[@"Harley",@"Jake",@"Levi",@"Zoe", @"Harley", @"Henry", @"Harley", @"Henry"];
NSArray *petNames;
NSMutableArray *tempPetNames = [@[] mutableCopy];
[objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx % 2 == 0) {
        [tempPetNames addObject:[@[obj, @""] mutableCopy]];
    } else {
        [tempPetNames lastObject][1] = obj;
    }
}];
petNames = [[[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:tempPetNames] array];
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I need to have names grouped in two's with a spacer object tagged on the end of the array which will appear either alone if the items are just a pair like: [Henry, Jake],[""] or if only one:[Henry, ""] or more fun like: [Henry, Jake], [Levi, Zoe], [Harley, ""]

- I hope that is helpful.

Comment: This doesn't clarify my request.

Comment: Here is the array objects:
Names objects: [(
    Diva,
    Macy,
    Tessa
)]

The assembled array should look like this:
names [(
        (
        Diva,
        Macy
    ),
        (
        Tessa,
        ""
    )
)]

I hope that is better.

Comment: both my codes do that. the question is when to delete duplicates.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Per - duplicates we do not want to see them. Each name should appear only once. If there are 5 names that should be five names plus the spacer in the assembled array. But to be extra clear, if there are 2 Henrys in the list because there are two names (people with the name Henry) that is acceptable, but not probable and is an edge case scenario as far as I am concerned.